# How to get array php in javascript using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, object

I have array object in php file, then I send arrayobject to ajax function but I don't understand how to display array content in a simple console log.

My file php:

```
$json = "";
try {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $list = Products::searchActiveProducts($id);
    $json = array(
        'status' => 'ok',
        'lista' => $list
    );
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $json = array(
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => $ex->getMessage()  
    );
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

My js function:

```
listActiveProducts: function() {
    var id = $("#txtId").val();
    $.ajax({
        type      : "POST",
        url       : "../ProductController.php",
        data      : {"id": id},
        dataType  : "json"
        success   : function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your array in a correct state while on the server? Does the PHP array `$list` contain the information you want?

Comment: `data.status` should be `ok`. `lista` seems to be an array, so you need the index to access it's items: `data.lista[0].something_I_dont_know_of`.

Comment: From the image I assume that the elements of `lista` are empty, hence the only member of the Object at the index 0 is the prototype.

Comment: It might be easier to look at the response you got. Instead of going to the console tab in your browser look at the network tab and click on the one the ajax request creates so you can look at the response the php file sends you.